# How to randomize names without repeating its name in a row when you click again the randomize function?

Tags: random, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good day. I am making a program to send monthly survey for IT employees with 46 members. Given the code in google app script in google sheet, how could I limit the names of ratees to appear again on the same row when I run randomize function in the 2nd to 6th times. Thank you.

About the code:

- It can generate randomize names with no duplicates per row, name1-name46.
- It can generate randomize name per column, name 1-46, all name1-46 were in each column
- When you rerun the given code, there is a possibility for the name in each row to appear again in the same row.

Problem:
Given the data below, ratee 1-5 should not appear again in the same row when you run randomize function 2nd-6th times.

[image: Data]
[image: Data]

```
    function randomize() {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var sheetname = "Emails";
          var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
          
          // some variables
          var randomcount = 2; // how many random names
          var rowstart = 2; // ignore row 1 - the header row
          var width = 6;    // how many names in each row - 1/rater plus 5/ratee
          var thelastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
          //Logger.log("DEBUG:last row = "+thelastrow)
        
          // get the employee names
          var employeecount = thelastrow-rowstart+1;
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: employee count = "+employeecount);//DEBUG
        
          // get the data
          var datarange = sheet.getRange(rowstart, 3, thelastrow - rowstart+1);
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: range = "+datarange.getA1Notation());//DEBUG
          var data = datarange.getValues();
          //Logger.log("data length = "+data.length);
          //Logger.log(data); 
        
        var data1d = data.map(function(e){return e[0]});
        var finalArr = getRandUniqMatrix(5, 46).map(function(row){return row.map(function(col){return data1d[col]})}); 
        sheet.getRange(2,4,finalArr.length, finalArr[0].length).setValues(finalArr);
          
        }


   //Credits to: TheMaster
   //@see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56588581 
        function getRandUniqMatrix(numCols, numRows) {
        
          var maxIter = 1000; //Worst case number of iterations, after which the loop and tempCol resets
          var output = Array.apply(null, Array(numRows)).map(function(_, i) {
        return [i++];
          });//[[1],[2],[3].....]
          var getRandom = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * numRows);
          };//getrandom number within numRows
          while (numCols--) {//loop through columns
        for (
          var row = 0, currRandNum = getRandom(), tempCol = [], iter = 0;
          row < numRows;
          ++row
        ) {//loop through rows
          //unique condition
          if (!~output[row].indexOf(currRandNum) && !~tempCol.indexOf(currRandNum)) {
            tempCol.push(currRandNum);
          } else {
            currRandNum = getRandom();//get a new random number
            --row;
            ++iter;
            if (iter > 1000) {//reset loop
              iter = 0;
              tempCol = [];
              row = -1;
            }
          }
          if (row + tempCol.length + 1 === numRows * 2) {//last row, Combine output+tempCol
            output.forEach(function(e, i) {
              return e.push(tempCol[i]);
            });
          }
        }
          }
          return output;
        }
        console.info(getRandUniqMatrix(5, 46));
```

Expected outcome:

Totally different names per row of ratees when you run randomize function in the 2nd,3rd,4th,5th and 6th times. In realworld application in sending survey,  we don't want to rate the same person next month or until 6th month.

Comment: There's a discrepency between how your sheets look in your images and how your script is filling the sheet on running `randomize()`. What if the formula in the Duplicate column? I'm not able to reproduce the duplication of a name in the same row with the provided script.

Comment: Thank you Sir Rafa, I already got the alternative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run the function 2 to 6 times. Run the function once with 30 column(5x6). Use the first 5 columns the first time, the next 5 columns second time and so on..

```
var finalArr = getRandUniqMatrix(30, 46).map(function(row){return row.map(function(col){return data1d[col]})});
```

Comment: Ow, i get it. Thanks the master, you are the best.